# Content aware dictionary update

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I really don't know how else to call this problem, but on my current project, I've already had too many workarounds avoiding it, so I'm asking for help.

Given this sample code,

```python
def sensitive_update(sensitive, updated):
  # ???


sensitive_data = {'user1': {'password' : '1234'}, 'user2': {'password': '4321'}}

updated_data = [
  {'user1': {'id': 13}},
  {'user2': {'password': '0000'}},
  {'user3': {'id': 14}}
  ]

for data in updated_data:
  sensitive_update(sensitive_data, data)

print(sensitive_data)
# should print
# {'user1': {'id': 13, 'password': '1234'}, 'user2': {'password': '0000'}, 'user3': {'id': 14}}
```

does there exist a mostly-builtin or a short way of writing `sensitive_update` function, or is manually looping through each value of a dictionary recursively unavoidable?

Edit:
Additional info: function merges all mergable dicts, and creates dicts and keys that do not exist

Comment: Is each element of `updated_data` always a dictionary with a single key? And what do you mean manually looping through the dictionary? You should be looping through the `updated_data` list...no?

Comment: `updated_data` can have more than one key.
Manually looping meant checking for matching key in `sensitive` for each key from `updated`, doing the same for values and their values and so on until a non-dict is found.

Comment: updated_data *has no keys*. It is a list. Please try to be precise, or else people will make different assumptions about what you mean, and there is already a non-ambiguous terminology to avoid that problem.

Comment: meant to write `updated` instead of `updated_data` on that comment, referring to function's parameters

Comment: [Addict](https://github.com/mewwts/addict) may be used to merge dictionaries of arbitrary depth: `d = Dict({'a': {'c': {'d': 4}}}); d.update({'a': {'c': {'f': 6}}}); d` => `{'a': {'c': {'d': 4, 'f': 6}}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would manually iterate through the *dictionary*, but here is the general approach to what you are trying to do:

```
In [3]: sensitive_data = {'user1': {'password' : '1234'}, 'user2': {'password': '4321'}}
   ...:

In [4]: updated_data = [
   ...:   {'user1': {'id': 13}},
   ...:   {'user2': {'password': '0000'}},
   ...:   {'user3': {'id': 14}}
   ...:   ]

In [5]: for data in updated_data:
   ...:     for k,v in data.items():
   ...:         sensitive_data.setdefault(k, {}).update(v)
   ...:

In [6]: sensitive_data
Out[6]:
{'user1': {'id': 13, 'password': '1234'},
 'user2': {'password': '0000'},
 'user3': {'id': 14}}
```

You can gain performance by using a `defaultdict` too instead of a plain `dict` with the `setdefault` method. Essentially, it is a dictionary with an optimized to do the `setdefault` method, but it works with normal key-access:

```
In [11]: sensitive_data = {'user1': {'password' : '1234'}, 'user2': {'password': '4321'}}
    ...:
    ...:

In [12]: from collections import defaultdict
In [13]: d = defaultdict(dict)

In [14]: d.update(sensitive_data) # convert plain dict to defaultdict

In [15]: d
Out[15]:
defaultdict(dict,
            {'user1': {'password': '1234'}, 'user2': {'password': '4321'}})

In [16]: for data in updated_data:
    ...:     for k,v in data.items():
    ...:         d[k].update(v)
    ...:

In [17]: d
Out[17]:
defaultdict(dict,
            {'user1': {'id': 13, 'password': '1234'},
             'user2': {'password': '0000'},
             'user3': {'id': 14}})
```

Comment: Gosh, how could I miss those? Thank you a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary's *update* method:

```
for data in updated_data:
    for k, v in data.items():
        if k in sensitive_data:        
            sensitive_data[k].update(v)  # update the information of the corresponding user
        else:
            sensitive_data[k] = v

sensitive_data
# {'user1': {'id': 13, 'password': '1234'},
#  'user2': {'password': '0000'},
#  'user3': {'id': 14}}
```